# Sql Query to Retrieve Path and file Name

Tags: sql

I need to retrieve the file name with extension from a database column.

example : from `c:\abc\bde\hyr\gff\test.txt`

I need to get the result like `test.txt`

and `c:\abc\bde\hyr\gff`

Please Help

Thanks

Comment: Using what version of SQL?  And what have you tried?

Comment: I suggest using SUBSTRING

Comment: Are you using: MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, PostgreSQL etc. ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
SELECT REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(columnName),CHARINDEX('\',REVERSE(columnName))-1)) AS FileName,
REVERSE(RIGHT(REVERSE(columnName),LEN(REVERSE(columnName)) - CHARINDEX('\',REVERSE(columnName)))) AS Directory
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to `SubString` would be to use the following, using `CharIndex` and `Reverse`:

```
Select  Left([FilePath], Len([FilePath]) - CharIndex('\', Reverse([FilePath])))     [FolderPath],
        Right('\' + [FilePath], CharIndex('\', Reverse('\' + [FilePath])) - (1))    [FileName]
```

This will pull everything after the last `\` as the FileName, and everything before as the FolderPath.